# Vue.js webpack call

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have this error when i run npm run dev, when i use npm run watch and i modify the vue the error gone.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=142bd79ca1dd6d40116a:64)
at Object../node_modules/css-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (12.js:556)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=142bd79ca1dd6d40116a:64)
at Object../node_modules/style-loader/index.js!./node_modules/css-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (12.js:576)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=142bd79ca1dd6d40116a:64)
at Module../node_modules/vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (12.js:1259)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=142bd79ca1dd6d40116a:64)
at Module../resources/js/components/BodyScanForm.vue (19.js:1769)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=142bd79ca1dd6d40116a:64)
at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/views/BodyScan/BodyScan.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (19.js:529)
```

I don't understand the error and where is the problem in the console

here the vue who make this error :

```
<script>
    import clone from 'lodash/clone'
    import TitleBar from '@/components/TitleBar'
    import HeroBar from '@/components/HeroBar'
    import Tiles from '@/components/Tiles'
    import CardComponent from '@/components/CardComponent'
    import FilePicker from '@/components/FilePicker'
    import VueNumberInput from '@chenfengyuan/vue-number-input'
    import CheckboxPicker from '@/components/CheckboxPicker'
    import RadioPicker from '@/components/RadioPicker'
    import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

    export default {
        name: 'BodyScanForm',
        components : { Multiselect, CheckboxPicker, RadioPicker,clone, Tiles, TitleBar, HeroBar, CardComponent, FilePicker, VueNumberInput },
```

also i don't understand why i get this output : with a lot of js, it should only build app.js when i make a npm run

```
    DONE  Compiled successfully in 29262ms                               8:02:02 PM

          Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
   /css/app.css   402 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
/css/vendor.css   255 KiB           [emitted]  
     /js/app.js  2.52 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
           0.js  37.8 KiB        0  [emitted]  
           1.js  16.9 KiB        1  [emitted]  
          10.js  69.2 KiB       10  [emitted]  
          11.js   145 KiB       11  [emitted]  
          12.js  40.5 KiB       12  [emitted]  
          13.js  43.5 KiB       13  [emitted]  
          14.js    44 KiB       14  [emitted]  
          15.js  40.9 KiB       15  [emitted]  
          16.js  27.5 KiB       16  [emitted]  
          17.js  62.5 KiB       17  [emitted]  
          18.js  21.7 KiB       18  [emitted]  
          19.js  25.6 KiB       19  [emitted]  
           2.js  37.5 KiB        2  [emitted]  
          20.js  7.97 KiB       20  [emitted]  
          21.js  12.1 KiB       21  [emitted]  
          22.js  10.5 KiB       22  [emitted]  
          23.js  10.8 KiB       23  [emitted]  
          24.js  58.1 KiB       24  [emitted]  
          25.js  4.88 KiB       25  [emitted]  
           3.js  25.8 KiB        3  [emitted]  
           4.js  37.2 KiB        4  [emitted]  
           5.js  52.6 KiB        5  [emitted]  
           6.js    63 KiB        6  [emitted]  
           7.js  43.3 KiB        7  [emitted]  
           8.js  17.5 KiB        8  [emitted]  
           9.js  62.1 KiB        9  [emitted]
```

Comment: Hello, what does npm run dev execute?

Comment: hi @Tolumide  > @ development /var/www
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

Comment: The `lof of .js` is actually called chunks. Webpack splits your codebase and loads the parts you need on demand... I would go through the updated question now and give you a response soon.

Comment: the vie file making the error seems incomplete. Can you update that? Also I meant what script does your npm run dev execute. Something like "dev": "webpack env.mode=development --open" ??

Comment: could we make a quick chat ? @Tolumide

Comment: Sure ..what platform?

Comment: i think we can on stackoverflow chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207548/discussion-between-mathieu-mourareau-and-tolumide).